# ¿Para qué sirven las llaves al definir constantes en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables-globales, constantes

Revisando diferentes códigos en GitHub he visto unas diferencias al momento de llamar ciertas constantes en Javascript, algunas veces he visto que las constantes las declaran con ciertas llaves como estas `{}`, pondré un ejemplo entre las dos formas que he visto para más detalle.

```
const descripcion = req.params.description
```

o

```
const {description} = req.body;
```

*¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estas dos constantes y para que son las llaves?*

He tratado de investigar, porque siempre lo hago antes de hacer una pregunta, pero no consigo dar con información clara y precisa. Espero que alguien con más experiencia pueda brindarme información al respecto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estas dos constantes y para que son las llaves?

Dejando de lado las diferencias obvias (que la primera da acceso a los parámetros de ruta y la segunda da acceso a las propiedades de una solicitud), ambas cumplen el mismo propósito, **acceder a una propiedad de un objeto.**

La diferencia es que la primera emplea el uso del operador punto (`.`), y la segunda emplea uso de una [asignación desestructurante](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) del objeto.

Teniendo este objeto:

```
let obj = {
    a: "foo",
    b: "bar"
}
```

Se tienen dos maneras de acceder a las propiedades:

*Por medio del operador punto (`.`)*

```js
let obj = {
    a: "foo",
    b: "bar"
}

console.log(obj.a);
console.log(obj.b);
```

*Por medio de desestructuración*

```js
let obj = {
    a: "foo",
    b: "bar"
}

let {a,b} = obj;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Las llaves no son más que una manera alternativa de acceder a la propiedades de un objeto.

```
const { propiedad } = objeto; // const propiedad = objeto.propiedad
```

Estas llaves que se emplean al desestructurar un objeto, sirven para asignar los valores de una propiedad del objeto a otra variable en especifico. Al final de cuentas ambas maneras cumplen la misma función.

Saludos.

Comment: Justamente hace unos días leyendo documentación había un hilo de desestructuración y me di cuenta de que trataba. Me parece una manera muy clara de obtener las propiedades de un objeto. Cada día más me atrae JavaScript.